# Messaging.SendEmailResult Type cannot be constructed?

Tags: apex, unit-test, singleemailmessage, mock

I'm trying to create a simple mock of messaging `Messaging.sendEmail` and in my code I'm trying to do the following to construct mocked instances of Messaging.SendEmailResult

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult result = new Messaging.SendEmailResult();
```

Compiler is giving the following error:

```
Type cannot be constructed: Messaging.SendEmailResult
```

Is there a work around?

**Edit:**

This doesn't work either:

```
Type t = Type.forName('Messaging', 'SendEmailResult');
Messaging.SendEmailResult newObj = (Messaging.SendEmailResult)t.newInstance();
```

Bummer...

Comment: It’s not constructed. It is returned only as part of messaging.send

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can construct the Messaging.SendEmailResult using the JSON deserializer

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult  er =(Messaging.SendEmailResult) JSON.deserialize('{}', Messaging.SendEmailResult.class);
System.debug(er);
```

Get your instance. Happy Days.

Comment: Now how the heck was I supposed to find that?? Thank you!! Can I do something similar for Messaging.SendEmailError?

Comment: Do you think I can do something with this to mock a SendMailResult? Can I put something into that empty json bracket? Very interested...

Comment: @mpaler these are little hack I found while coding on platform. That being said I dont see why you should not be able to reproduce the SendEmail error. I have not tried to put values in empty JSON so cant say it accepts all. Buy try and let us know if it does.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying `Messaging.SendEmailError s2 =(Messaging.SendEmailError) JSON.deserialize('{}', Messaging.SendEmailError.class);
System.debug('debug: ' + s2);` and debug gives `11:11:30.19 (30504543)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 377575750-91930 (243059598) (243059598)` Frankly, not sure what/how to pass anything to the deserialize step. Will continue banging my head...

Answer (score 5):

Since the properties of this class are not in the official salesforce documentation, hopefully this helps someone.
If you need to create an instance of this that return false for isSuccess()

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult failedMessageResult = (Messaging.SendEmailResult)JSON.deserialize('{"success":false}', Messaging.SendEmailResult.class);
```

Comment: this is incomplete, there is also the `errors` property which is a `List<Messaging.SendEmailError>` which has three properties: `message`, `statusCode`, `targetObjectId`